# Access to socket stream directly ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: sockets, streaming, asp.net-core-6.0

I have to access to socket stream which  asp.net provide for reading and writing requests and responses but I want it without http protocol on it.

An example for what I want is websocket. I know I have to send these http headers

```
connection: upgrade
upgrade: websocket , http2 , myprotocol
```

but I don't know how to get stream.

I hope you understand my question

Thanks

I want it in .NET 6

I checked by Google but I didn't find anything

Comment: Hi,have you checked the document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0? where do you want accept websocket request, any codes related?

Comment: I checked the source code but it is too messed up,  before .net 6 I found out how to get socket stream by looking at the source code of web socket and upgrade it to bi directional stream , but now I can not find it

Comment: i found it , in github dotnet/aspnetcore , this interface is responsible for getting the bi directional stream : IHttpUpgradeFeature.UpgradeAsync

Answer (score 0):

the answer is this interface IHttpUpgradeFeature.UpgradeAsync
I searched websocket source code in the github
and I found it in "dotnet/aspnetcore" and now
I remember it and Microsoft didn't changed it